# Python code for counting number of zero crossings in an array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, distribution

I am looking to count the number of times the values in an array change in polarity (EDIT: Number of times the values in an array cross zero).

Suppose I have an array:

```
[80.6  120.8  -115.6  -76.1  131.3  105.1  138.4  -81.3
 -95.3  89.2  -154.1  121.4  -85.1  96.8  68.2]`
```

I want the count to be 8.

One solution is to run a loop and check for greater than or less than 0, and keep a history of the previous polarity.

Can we do this faster?

EDIT: My purpose is really to find something faster, because I have these arrays of length around 68554308, and I have to do these calculations on 100+ such arrays.

Comment: Are you sure your expected count is 8, not 6?

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for the number of zero crossings?

Comment: the solution that yourself suggested seems to be a good one.
you're not looking for a faster solution, but a solution with less code.

Comment: @Scott, yes, I am looking for the number of zero crossings.

Comment: @zero.zero.seven, I am actually looking for something faster. See EDIT in my question.

Comment: You should consider parallelising your code: look at `multiprocessing.Pool.map_async`, https://github.com/pydata/numexpr , PyCUDA, or MapReduce.

Comment: @RahulMurmuria There seems to be a different result provided by the numpy solution as compared to the others.  I don't know which is correct.  I posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279315/different-results-to-counting-zero-crossings-of-a-large-sequence

Comment: Got an answer to my question in the link above. Might be of use to you.

Comment: @Scott, sorry I wasn't around during your delving. I had investigated this issue myself and found that 0 is handled differently while reading the documentation for np.diff(). I don't have any 0 in my arrays so it is a non-issue in my case. However, it is vital to understand this for any other applications.

Comment: Ok good. I was just curious myself and thought you should be aware (which you were).  If you didn't see it you should check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30279745/4663466

Comment: Indeed! I have been experimenting with that. Seems so simple, I would have never attempted doing that multiplication, betting that it would be too costly. Definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This produces the same result:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.array([80.6, 120.8, -115.6, -76.1, 131.3, 105.1, 138.4, -81.3, -95.3,  
                     89.2, -154.1, 121.4, -85.1, 96.8, 68.2])
((my_array[:-1] * my_array[1:]) < 0).sum()
```

gives:

```
8
```

and seems to be the fastest solution:

```
%timeit ((my_array[:-1] * my_array[1:]) < 0).sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.6 µs per loop
```

Compared to the fastest so far:

```
%timeit (np.diff(np.sign(my_array)) != 0).sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.2 µs per loop
```

Also for larger arrays:

```
big = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=10000000)
```

this:

```
%timeit ((big[:-1] * big[1:]) < 0).sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 62.1 ms per loop
```

vs:

```
%timeit (np.diff(np.sign(big)) != 0).sum()
1 loops, best of 3: 97.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for posting here.

Comment: This won't account for a list like `[ 1,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -1,  0,  1,  0]`. Wouldn't we want to add: `... + (x == 0)`?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `numpy` solution. Numpy's methods are generally pretty fast and well-optimized, but if you're not already working with `numpy` there's probably some overhead from converting the list to a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [80.6, 120.8, -115.6, -76.1, 131.3, 105.1, 138.4, -81.3, -95.3,  89.2, -154.1, 121.4, -85.1, 96.8, 68.2]
(np.diff(np.sign(my_list)) != 0).sum()
Out[8]: 8
```

Comment: This is crazy fast.  I ran this against my and @Alik solution and I get a different result using numpy.  Any idea why?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279315/different-results-to-counting-zero-crossings-of-a-large-sequence.

Comment: This counts an extra crossing for each 0 in the input. I think that's fixed by doing the following: `(np.diff(np.sign(my_list)) != 0).sum() - (my_list == 0).sum()`

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272583/471899)

The generator expression proposed by Scott uses `enumerate` which returns tuples containing index and list item. List item are not used in the expression at all and discarded later. So better solution in terms of time would be

```
sum(1 for i in range(1, len(a)) if a[i-1]*a[i]<0)
```

If your list `a` is really huge, [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) may throw an exception. You can replace it with `itertools.islice` and `itertools.count`.

In Python version 2.x, use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of Python 3's `range`.
In Python 3, `xrange` is no longer available.

Comment: This **does not work when there is a zero** in the array! `[ 1, 2, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 2]` should yield `2` zero crossings, which it does not. Here is [a solution that handles zeros correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40809378/2192488).

Answer (score 1):

I think a loop is a straight forward way to go:

```
a = [80.6, 120.8, -115.6, -76.1, 131.3, 105.1, 138.4, -81.3, -95.3, 89.2, -154.1, 121.4, -85.1, 96.8, 68.2]

def change_sign(v1, v2):
    return v1 * v2 < 0

s = 0
for ind, _ in enumerate(a):
    if ind+1 < len(a):
        if change_sign(a[ind], a[ind+1]):
            s += 1
print s  # prints 8
```

You could use a generator expression but it gets ugly:

```
z_cross = sum(1 for ind, val in enumerate(a) if (ind+1 < len(a)) 
              if change_sign(a[ind], a[ind+1]))
print z_cross  # prints 8
```

**EDIT:**

@Alik pointed out that for huge lists the best option in space and time (at least out of the solutions we have considered) is not to call `change_sign` in the generator expression but to simply do:

```
z_cross = sum(1 for i, _ in enumerate(a) if (i+1 < len(a)) if a[i]*a[i+1]<0)
```

Comment: Just a note: `v1` and `v2` have different signs if `v1*v2 < 0`, so you can simplify your code a little bit

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that as I was writing it.  Do you think that makes it less readable?

Comment: I am not sure, I am used to testing signs with multiplication so for me it makes code more readable. Anyway you can always leave a comment about `change_sign` function

Comment: It might be useful in your generator expression, but it will certainly require a comment. `z_cross = sum(1 for i, _ in enumerate(a) if (i+1 < len(a)) if a[i]*a[i+1]<0)`. Also note, that this is not a list comprehension, but  a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#rationale).

Comment: @Alik I agree, which is why I wrote the (mostly useless) function with a human readable name `change_sign`.  Anyway, I think the short answer, among our many long answers, to the original question is: No, stick with a loop.  Though there could be something in scipy/numpy since zero-crossings pops up a bit in signal processing.

Comment: @Alik Also thanks for highlighting your link, edited from list comprehension to generator.  I started trying to solve this with list comprehension but then saw that '@fmatheis' beat me to it.

Comment: @Scott, I hope there is something in scipy/numpy that is faster! Thank you for actively brainstorming. I will spend a few more minutes on this before selecting an answer.

Comment: @RahulMurmuria If you have truly huge lists, the generator expression is a good choice as far as memory use.

Comment: @Scott, did a few tests. Plain cycle seems to be the slowest solution, then goes your generator expression and [modified generator expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272538/python-code-for-counting-number-of-zero-crossings-in-an-array#comment48645217_30272583) leads by 25%

Comment: @Alik Wow.  I was running timeit as well and added the "modified generator expression" after your comment.  That's impressive what a function call does 1e7 times.  I'll point that out in my answer.

Comment: @Alik, I checked Soon's answer as well and it seems that the "modified generator expression" is the fastest

Comment: @Alik, I suppose Marius has given a faster solution!

Comment: @RahulMurmuria test it, upvote and accept it then. Upvote Scott's answer as well, because someone might might find his approach useful

Comment: This **does not work when there is a zero** in the array! `[ 1, 2, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 2]` should yield `2` zero crossings, which it does not. Here is [a solution that handles zeros correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40809378/2192488).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, you want to group numbers by their sign. This could be done using built-in method `groupby`:

```
In [2]: l = [80.6,  120.8,  -115.6,  -76.1,  131.3,  105.1,  138.4,  -81.3, -95.3,  89.2,  -154.1,  121.4,  -85.1,  96.8,  68.2]

In [3]: from itertools import groupby

In [5]: list(groupby(l, lambda x: x < 0))
Out[5]: 
[(False, <itertools._grouper at 0x7fc9022095f8>),
 (True, <itertools._grouper at 0x7fc902209828>),
 (False, <itertools._grouper at 0x7fc902209550>),
 (True, <itertools._grouper at 0x7fc902209e80>),
 (False, <itertools._grouper at 0x7fc902209198>),
 (True, <itertools._grouper at 0x7fc9022092e8>),
 (False, <itertools._grouper at 0x7fc902209240>),
 (True, <itertools._grouper at 0x7fc902209908>),
 (False, <itertools._grouper at 0x7fc9019a64e0>)]
```

Then you should use function `len` which returns the number of groups:

```
In [7]: len(list(groupby(l, lambda x: x < 0)))
Out[7]: 9
```

Obviously, there will be at least one group (for a non-empty list), but if you want to count the number of points, where a sequence changes its polarity, you could just subtract one group. Do not forget about the empty-list case.

You should also take care about zero elements: shouldn't they be extracted into another group? If so, you could just change the `key` argument (lambda function) of `groupby` function.

Comment: Very promising solution! Could this be faster than looping? I am running some tests.

Comment: this is definitely a different approach, but using groupby and lambda will make more expensive than using a simple for loop..

Comment: @RahulMurmuria, no, this can't be faster, than looping, but it is definitely more readable than regular loop-based solution. If you are talking about speed, you should also provide the worst case and expected time.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using list comprehension:

```
myList = [80.6, 120.8, -115.6, -76.1, 131.3, 105.1, 138.4, -81.3, -95.3,  89.2, -154.1, 121.4, -85.1, 96.8, 68.2]
len([x for i, x in enumerate(myList) if i > 0 and ((myList[i-1] > 0 and myList[i] < 0) or (myList[i-1] < 0 and myList[i] > 0))])
```

Comment: on the first iteration aren't you comparing the last value in mylist with the first? i.e. when `i=0` you have `myList[-1]>0 and myList[0]<0...`

Comment: This could be bad say if the first value was -80.6, in our example we would expect 9 zero crossings, but your solution will give 10.

Comment: Thanks Scott, it is true, I added a condition to fix that problem.