# Different results to counting zero-crossings of a large sequence

Tags: python, numpy

This question stems from looking at the answers provided to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272538/python-code-for-counting-number-of-zero-crossings-in-an-array/) question regarding **counting** the number of **[zero crossings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_crossing)**.  Several answer were provided that solve the problem, but the NumPy [appproach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30273428/4663466) destroyed the others with respect to time.

When I compared four of the answers however I notice that the NumPy solution provides a different result for large sequences.  The four answers in question are [loop and simple generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272583/4663466), [better generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30273456/4663466) , and [NumPy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30273428/4663466).

**Question:  Why does the NumPy solution provide a different result than the other three?** (and which is correct?)

Here are the results for counting the number of zero crossings:

```
Blazing fast NumPy solution
total time: 0.303605794907 sec
Zero Crossings Small: 8
Zero Crossings Med: 54464
Zero Crossings Big: 5449071

Loop solution
total time: 15.6818780899 sec
Zero Crossings Small: 8
Zero Crossings Med: 44960
Zero Crossings Big: 4496847

Simple generator expression solution
total time: 16.3374049664 sec
Zero Crossings Small: 8
Zero Crossings Med: 44960
Zero Crossings Big: 4496847

Modified generator expression solution
total time: 13.6596589088 sec
Zero Crossings Small: 8
Zero Crossings Med: 44960
Zero Crossings Big: 4496847
```

And the code used to get the results:

```
import time
import numpy as np

def zero_crossings_loop(sequence):
    s = 0
    for ind, _ in enumerate(sequence):
        if ind+1 < len(sequence):
            if sequence[ind]*sequence[ind+1] < 0:
                s += 1
    return s

def print_three_results(r1, r2, r3):
    print 'Zero Crossings Small:', r1
    print 'Zero Crossings Med:', r2
    print 'Zero Crossings Big:', r3
    print '\n'

small = [80.6, 120.8, -115.6, -76.1, 131.3, 105.1, 138.4, -81.3, -95.3, 89.2, -154.1, 121.4, -85.1, 96.8, 68.2]
med = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=100000)
big = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=10000000)

print 'Blazing fast NumPy solution'
tic = time.time()
z1 = (np.diff(np.sign(small)) != 0).sum()
z2 = (np.diff(np.sign(med)) != 0).sum()
z3 = (np.diff(np.sign(big)) != 0).sum()
print 'total time: {0} sec'.format(time.time()-tic)
print_three_results(z1, z2, z3)

print 'Loop solution'
tic = time.time()
z1 = zero_crossings_loop(small)
z2 = zero_crossings_loop(med)
z3 = zero_crossings_loop(big)
print 'total time: {0} sec'.format(time.time()-tic)
print_three_results(z1, z2, z3)

print 'Simple generator expression solution'
tic = time.time()
z1 = sum(1 for i, _ in enumerate(small) if (i+1 < len(small)) if small[i]*small[i+1] < 0)
z2 = sum(1 for i, _ in enumerate(med) if (i+1 < len(med)) if med[i]*med[i+1] < 0)
z3 = sum(1 for i, _ in enumerate(big) if (i+1 < len(big)) if big[i]*big[i+1] < 0)
print 'total time: {0} sec'.format(time.time()-tic)
print_three_results(z1, z2, z3)

print 'Modified generator expression solution'
tic = time.time()
z1 = sum(1 for i in xrange(1, len(small)) if small[i-1]*small[i] < 0)
z2 = sum(1 for i in xrange(1, len(med)) if med[i-1]*med[i] < 0)
z3 = sum(1 for i in xrange(1, len(big)) if big[i-1]*big[i] < 0)
print 'total time: {0} sec'.format(time.time()-tic)
print_three_results(z1, z2, z3)
```

Comment: Aside: right now, your non-numpy methods (treating them as your reference behaviour) would say that [-1,0,1,0,-1] never crossed zero, because you're only looking for when you cross zero in one step. Is that what you intended?

Comment: That was my interpretation of the original question. I'll leave the decision of what is correct to the question's author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solutions differ in their treatment of zero. The numpy.diff solution will still return a diff going from -1 to 0 or 1 to 0, counting those as a zero crossing, while your iterative solutions don't because they use the product being less than zero as their criterion. Instead, test for `<= 0`, and the numbers will be equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

I get the same results as the loop with:

```
((array[:-1] * array[1:]) < 0).sum()
```

This:

```
small = np.array([80.6, 120.8, -115.6, -76.1, 131.3, 105.1, 138.4, -81.3,
                 -95.3, 89.2, -154.1, 121.4, -85.1, 96.8, 68.2])
med = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=100000)
big = np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=10000000)

for name, array in [('small', small), ('med', med), ('big', big)]:
    print('loop ', name, zero_crossings_loop(array))
    print('Numpy', name, ((array[:-1] * array[1:]) < 0).sum())
```

prints:

```
loop  small 8
Numpy small 8
loop  med 44901
Numpy med 44901
loop  big 4496911
Numpy big 4496911
```

**UDPATE**

This version avoids the problem with zeros:

```
def numpy_zero_crossings2(array):
    nonzero_array = array[np.nonzero(array)]
    return ((nonzero_array[:-1] * nonzero_array[1:]) < 0).sum()
```

It gives the same result as the answer by @djsutton:

```
>>> numpy_zero_crossings2(big) == numpy_zero_crossings(big)     
True
```

but seesm a bit faster:

```
%timeit numpy_zero_crossings2(big)
1 loops, best of 3: 194 ms per loop
```

vs:

```
%timeit numpy_zero_crossings(big)
1 loops, best of 3: 227 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is actually faster than the numpy.diff/numpy.sign solution.  Very cool.  @RahulMurmuria, this is faster than fast!  With the option to count zeros as well as crossings (or not) by using either `<0` or `<=0`.  Though it doesn't address @djsutton observation.  Not saying that it was supposed to.

Comment: You could post this as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272538/python-code-for-counting-number-of-zero-crossings-in-an-array/ and point out that it can solve both cases counting zero and not.

Answer (score 3):

Both the iterative and numpy solutions do not do well at counting crossings when a data element is equal to zero.  For the data [1,0,-1] the iterative solution gives 0 crossings and the numpy solution gives 2 crossings, neither of which seems correct.

One solution would be to drop data elements equal to zero. In NumPy you might try something like

```
def numpy_zero_crossings(data):
    return (np.diff(np.sign(data)[np.nonzero(data)]) != 0).sum()
```

However, this introduces another iteration through the array, so it will increase run time by another O(n)

Comment: Great observation. @RahulMurmuria might be interested in this.